# d3.js How to change property of all elements (rects or lines) at once with a function call?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to adapt a blocks example of a multi-line chart to my own data like so:
http://sunnysideworks.nyc/Simply-Run/blog2

The adaptation was a fairly smooth process, but I would like to add a feature that allows users to select and add all countries or select and remove all countries from the line graph.

I tried the following to update all the relevant attributes, d.visible, like so:

```
  function showAllCountries() {

        issue.selectAll("rect").attr("d", function(d){ d.visible = true;});


        issue.select("path")
          .transition()
          .attr("d", function(d){
            return d.visible ? line(d.values) : null; // If d.visible is true then draw line for this d selection
          })

        issue.select("rect")
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return d.visible ? color(d.name) : "#F1F1F2";
        });

    }
```

The function declaration doesn't cause an error, but if I run it, I get a reference error indicating that `issue` does not exist even though I only try calling the above function after `issue` has been declared and had the `rects` and `lines` appended to it. What is causing this error?

I'm pasting the setup code at the bottom in case it's helpful...

Here is how the lines are initially added:

```
 issue.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("pointer-events", "none") // Stop line interferring with cursor
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return "line-" + d.name.replace(" ", "").replace("/", ""); // Give line id of line-(insert issue name, with any spaces replaced with no spaces)
      })
      .attr("d", function(d) { 
        return d.visible ? line(d.values) : null; // If array key "visible" = true then draw line, if not then don't 
      })
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")//use clip path to make irrelevant part invisible
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Here is how the rects you can click to add and remove lines are initially added:

```
  issue.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)                                    
      .attr("x", width + (margin.right/3) - 15) 
      .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (legendSpace)+i*(legendSpace) - 8; })  // spacing
      .attr("fill",function(d) {
        return d.visible ? color(d.name) : "#F1F1F2"; // If array key "visible" = true then color rect, if not then make it grey 
      })
      .attr("class", "legend-box")

      .on("click", function(d){ // On click make d.visible 
        d.visible = !d.visible; // If array key for this data selection is "visible" = true then make it false, if false then make it true

        maxY = findMaxY(categories); // Find max Y rating value categories data with "visible"; true
        yScale.domain([0,maxY]); // Redefine yAxis domain based on highest y value of categories data with "visible"; true
        svg.select(".y.axis")
          .transition()
          .call(yAxis);   

        issue.select("path")
          .transition()
          .attr("d", function(d){
            return d.visible ? line(d.values) : null; // If d.visible is true then draw line for this d selection
          })

        issue.select("rect")
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return d.visible ? color(d.name) : "#F1F1F2";
        });
      })

      .on("mouseover", function(d){

        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

        d3.select("#line-" + d.name.replace(" ", "").replace("/", ""))
          .transition()
          .style("stroke-width", 2.5);  
      })

      .on("mouseout", function(d){

        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return d.visible ? color(d.name) : "#F1F1F2";});

        d3.select("#line-" + d.name.replace(" ", "").replace("/", ""))
          .transition()
          .style("stroke-width", 1.5);
      })
```

Comment: You're calling `showAllCountries()` before `issues` has been defined or in a different context. You need to make sure that `issues` is accessible within the function if you implement it this way.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I agree that this is happening for that reason, but I don't understand why. I have tried calling showAllCountries() in all sorts of locations, and I always get this error message. I am definitely not calling it before issues has been defined. I have tried calling it after paths and rects are both appended to issues, for example, and gotten that same error.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The working version is the web page I linked to. I will try to make it shorter, but I think that might turn it into a different problem at some point. Will post an updated link when I've made it shorter.

Comment: It's really crucial to see the non-working version to figure out what's wrong.